# Different between a method marked @Transaciotn call a method that doesn't mark Transaction

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I have question for all, please help me explain it.
**I have class A that was marked @Transaction annotation, this class has method a

I have class B that was also marked @Transaction annotation, this has method b

I have class C that was NOT marked @Transaction annotation, this has method c**

*

1. > What is difference between (a call b) and (a call c)?

*

Comment: The outer transaction A will remain active in both cases. B could declare @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW) to start a new transaction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default propagation of `@Transaction` is `Required`, which means, if a transaction exists, ok, use that one, otherwise create one.

So...

`a()`... -> create transaction, since none exists

...`b()` -> transaction exists, use that one, @transaction does nothing, so `b()` runs in `a()`'s transaction

...and...

`a()`... -> create transaction, since none exists

...`c()` -> transaction exists, no `@Transactional`, so `a()`'s will be used

So, both cases are pretty much equal. Would be different if, for example, `d()` had a `@Transcational(propagation=Propagation.REQUIRES_NEW)` :

`a()`... -> create transaction, since none exists

....`d()` -> Transaction exists, but `d()` requires a new one, so make new one